# C program to read specific lines from a file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to make a program that will count the lines in a file and will refer to specific lines as another count(i.e lines that start with a # should not be counted)

```
  while(fgets(tempstring,sizeof(tempstring),fptr)){
    lines++;
    if(tempstring[0] != '#' || tempstring[0]!='\n'|| tempstring[0]!=' '){
        ++count;
        }
```

Now what am I doing wrong here?

Also i have noticed that the first time i call fgets i get `∩` as an output for `tempstring[0]` why is that?

Comment: `tempstring[0] != '#' || tempstring[0]!='\n'|| tempstring[0]!=' '` is always true.

Comment: Note that `fgets` may not read a complete line.

Comment: This is why planning out your code on paper first is helpful, especially when you're new. Please get into the habit of doing that. Over time, you'll get better and be able to do it in your head, but trying to write code from scratch at the very beginning is like trying to pilot a fighter jet with no experience using a joystick. You can go from where you are now to writing code from scratch, but you need to practice those skills, and if you don't, you're gonna get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is always true - you wanted to either use `&&`, or negate the overall `||`:

```
if (tempstring[0] != '#' && tempstring[0]!='\n' && tempstring[0]!=' ')
```

or

```
if(!(tempstring[0] == '#' || tempstring[0] == '\n' || tempstring[0] == ' '))
```

which is equivalent. Note that you can remove `if` altogether, because `true` in C is the same as `1`:

```
count += (tempstring[0] != '#' && tempstring[0]!='\n' && tempstring[0]!=' ');
```

Also note that `fgets` may or may not give you the beginning of line, depending on `sizeof(tempstring)`. If `tempstring` is not long enough for the whole string from the file, your call may produce a string from the middle of another string, causing incorrect behavior. This is harder to fix, because now you need a loop that checks for the *last* character of the string returned from `fgets` to be `'\n'`.

Comment: And you can have 1 additional caveat if the file has no POSIX `'\n'` at the end of the last line. In which case you will need to either set a flag (e.g. `int feol = 0;` on each read and set `feol = 1;` when each line ending is validated. After you exit the read loop, you will need to check if `tempstring && !feol` and handle the last line input (increment your count by `1`) if the character tests are passed.